# How to write JS module for exporting both default and non default functions / methods

Tags: javascript, class, webpack, import, es6-modules

I'm used to write classes in JS modules like the following:

```
class Auth{
  constructor() {
    init();        
  }

  init() {
    // ...
  }

  getUserData() {
    // ...
  }

  signin(username, password) {
     // ...
  }
}
export default new Auth();
```

My code is then optimized with Webpack. My goal is minimize the bundles size. For some applications, I don't need all the methods of my class. But most of the time, my methods use `this` to share variables.

With classes, tree shaking can't remove dead code. For example, if I never use the `getUserData()`, it will be imported anyway because the method is part of the class.

How could I rewrite my module to be able to import only some methods

```
import {init, getUserData} from "auth.js"
```

and also all the methods at once:

```
import auth from "auth.js"
```

Comment: If you're using `this` anywhere, it will no work with destructuring. And if you're no using `this` at all, then you don't need a class. Meaning that you can change that to exporting a bunch of functions.

Comment: @JakubKotrs I already understand it. For example, I may import init and getUserId that share a common object that replaces `this`

Comment: In that case, I'm gonna make a simple answer with how to import it.

Comment: @JakubKotrs please note that `import { blah } from './bah'` is not destructuring. They are [named imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#named_import).

Answer (score 1):

A class in JS is a fancy-pants sugar but you can't use it with destructuring (and so the methods can't even be named exports for the same reason).

```
const person = new Human()

const { eat, drink } = person

// this would probably not work
eat()
drink()
```

The reason is that you will lose context (the value of `this`) when you're destructuring. And therefore if you tried to export individual methods as named exports.

So to achieve what you're asking about, you need to export a bunch of functions from a closure

```
// to share a variable, you need to put it into the top level scope
let something

export function eat() {
  something = true
}
export function drink() {
  if (something) {
    foo()
  } else {
    bar()
  }
}
```

both of those functions would be using `state` instead of `this`, the module itself acts as a closure.

Now, as for the imports, you can have it both ways if you approach it as a namespace:

```
import { eat, drink } from './person'
import * as person from './person' // this is the "import namespace" pattern

// both work
eat()
person.eat()
```

If you absolutely need to, you can then also make a default export

```
export function eat() {}
export function drink() {}
export default { eat, drink }
```

for importing as default:

```
import person from './person'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to import everything without the star ? Should I create and object containing all the functions and export it as default ?

Comment: I added that now

Comment: I just try it, I can't share variable between functions.

Comment: Beware of scope, you would have to defined those variable outside of them, let me update the answer.

Comment: Since you are enclosing a mutable state at a module level, from Webpack's perspective, it is not free from sideEffects and in general won't do aggressive tree shaking even if you export individual functions. Try it and then see. Also, keep in mind that Webpack's default output is not exactly ESM!